# Which thread does Volley serve response on when run through SyncAdapter?

Tags: multithreading, android-volley

I have an extremely simple question. Couldn't find the answer anywhere online.

My app has a syncadapter that uses Volley to perform a request in the onPerformSync method.

My question is that when volley's Response.Lisener is triggered, does the onResponse method run on the main thread or on the same thread as the onPerformSync method?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the main thread .. because of ExecutorDelivery:

```
 mResponsePoster = new Executor() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Runnable command) {
            handler.post(command);
        }
    };
```

where: handler is created here (in the request queue):

```
 public RequestQueue(Cache cache, Network network, int threadPoolSize) {
    this(cache, network, threadPoolSize,
            new ExecutorDelivery(new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())));
}
```

you can override this behavior by passing your own ResponseDelivery implementation

Comment: added more info :)